# AMD Fusion GPU passthrough to KVM or Xen

Tags: virtualization, xen, kvm-virtualization

Has anyone successfully gotten a passthrough working with the GPU portion of AMD's Fusion APUs (the E-350 is my target) on top of a Linux hypervisor? IE, I want to dedicate the GPU to one VM only, excluding all other VMs as well as the host.  I know PCI passthrough can work with patches / kernel rebuilds for [Xen](https://serverfault.com/a/275595/74317) and [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/How_to_assign_devices_with_VT-d_in_KVM?).  However, since the GPU is on the same chip, I don't know if the host OS will see it as PCI.

I know there are a number of tangential issues here, such as:

- Poor Fusion drivers in Linux at the moment
- Unsuccessful patching efforts seem common
- VT-d / IOMMU is required and (from my reading) is supported on the APU, but the motherboard may not offer it
- KVM doesn't appear to support primary graphics cards, only secondary graphics cards (described [here](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/How_to_assign_devices_with_VT-d_in_KVM?))

However, I'd like to hear from anyone who has messed with this, even failed attempts.  Fedora + KVM is my preferred virtualization platform but I'm willing to change that if it makes a difference.

EDIT: The goal is to do this for a Windows 7 guest (I know it's asking a lot). Regardless, just assume this is HVM, not PV.

Comment: What OS is the target guest VM running? Linux?

Comment: @ewwhite: Win7, I added it to the post above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you'll need an IOMMU/vt-d for HVM passthrough. The E-350 / Bobcat has no IOMMU support.